# How to select U.S. Letter (8 1/2" by 11") paper size setting in the Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, paper

The journal requires the page size in U.S. Letter (8 1/2" by 11"). But how to change to this size? I could not find the settings in the picture below.

[Word 2016 settings for paper size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV7Cx.png)

Comment: Off-topic (Not sarcasm): US needs to change its metrics.

Comment: do you mean I need to post this somewhere else?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure sets the size of your custom need:

- Choose a **page size**
- Select the **Page Design** tab
- In the **Page Setup** group, select **Size** and click the icon that represents the page size that you want (Letter in your case).
- If you don’t see the size you want click **More Preset Page Sizes** (or click **Create New Page Size** to create a custom page size).

Comment: Thank you. As I checked, I think I am already using the required size. http://www.papersizes.org/us-paper-sizes.htm  shows that 8 1/2" by 11" is just 216 x 279 mm. While in Word 2016, it is 21.59 cm x 27.94 cm. So I think they are meaning the same thing.

Comment: While the A4 is the official standard: 210 x 297 mm that equals 8.3 x 11.7 in, the US Letter paper measures at 8.5" by 11" (215.9x279.4mm) so yes, it's correct.

Comment: US Letter size is only allowed to be measured in units of inches.  It isn't allowed to be expressed in metric units.  :-)

Comment: I disagree because the US metric system is being assimilated into the world-wide I.S. one. Just look at the new road markings.